# Is it possible to simulate UDP hole punching with docker networks in a local environment?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, sockets, network-programming, p2p

### TL;DR:

Is it possible to set up a peer-to-peer network with python and containerised the application for local development?

### Long version:

I am developing a hybrid peer-to-peer network. I have successfully followed an initial guide from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbzGL_tjmv4&ab_channel=EngineerMan)

I have been able to run the code **remotely**, with the server and clients hosted on AWS ec2 instances.

For the sake of development purposes, I want to containerise the server and client applications and run them **locally**

I have tried to create a MAC VLAN network in docker do allow static IP addresses to be used, using :

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet 192.168.44.108/24 --gateway 192.168.44.1  -o parent=bnep0 my-macvlan-network
```

I then specified static IP addresses for the server and client containers, and deploy them via;
Server:

```
docker run -it --rm  --network my-macvlan-network -p 4404:4404/udp --ip 192.168.44.144 --name server server:latest
```

clients 1:

```
docker run -it --rm  --network my-macvlan-network -p 2202:2202/udp -p 3303:3303/udp --ip **192.168.44.145** --name **client1** client:latest
```

and client 2:

```
docker run -it --rm  --network my-macvlan-network -p 2202:2202/udp -p 3303:3303/udp --ip **192.168.44.146** --name **client2** client:latest
```

attaching them to my macvlan network.

Now the containerised clients are able to connect to the containerised server, and the IP information exchange occurs between clients.

But when my python script gets to the stage **following** the actual UDP hole punch between the containerised clients, the python script for the clients fails with this error; stating that the address is already in use for the client and a socket cannot be bound to it:

```
Exception in thread => Thread-1 (listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/client.py", line 36, in listen
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", src_port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

here is the listen function started in the thread (I know you will probably want more information).

*should I be passing in the bounded sock object created into listen function, rather than redefining it?*

```
def listen(src_port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    **sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", src_port))**

    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print(f"\rclient: {data.decode()}\n", end="")
```

Now inside my script I can see that `socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", src_port))` is called earlier before the initialising of thread, as such:

```
print("Punching hole with client peers... ")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
**sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", src_port))**
sock.sendto(b"0", (ip, trg_port))

print("Ready to compute!")
**listener = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(src_port,), daemon=True)**
listener.start()
```

But this was **not** an issue with the **remote deployment test**, so I am not too sure if this is a consequence of trying to set up a local development environment, or if it is **not feasible** to begin with.

Do any networking wizards know if setting up a local containerised peer to peer networking development environment that uses UDP hole punching is possible? Is it the network type I have made a mistake with? Do the nodes in my network have different networks?

**Note:**
I have also tried providing a cpuset via the command flag `-cpuset-cpus="0-3"` during the docker run command, with no success. (I thought it may have been restricted to one thread).

Comment: It seems like you're calling `bind(("0.0.0.0", src_port))` both in the main thread and also the thread launched by the `listen()` function.  If you wind up with two open sockets both trying to bind to the same port then you'll get this error.  If you're opening the socket in the main function, it seems better to pass that socket into the listener thread than to re-open it.  (This shouldn't be Docker-specific.)

Comment: any word on this? I'm unable to implement UDP hole punching in docker while it works fine outside the docker image

Comment: was anyone able to do this? I'm trying to simulate it and I'm unable to as well